# Assign field value to an object does not infer value type corresponding its field

Tags: typescript, types, type-constraints

The `Payload<T>` type have `fieldName` and `value` properties. The `fieldName` should be the property type of the `CounterState` type and the `value` should be the type corresponding to its field.

```
type PayloadAction<P = void, T extends string = string, M = never, E = never> = {
    payload: P;
    type: T;
} & ([M] extends [never] ? {} : {
    meta: M;
}) & ([E] extends [never] ? {} : {
    error: E;
})

export interface CounterState {
  id: string;
  status: 'idle' | 'loading' | 'failed';
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

type Payload<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    fieldName: K;
    value: T[K];
  };
}[keyof T];
type T0 = Payload<CounterState>;

const initialState: CounterState = {
  id: '',
  email: '',
  password: '',
  status: 'idle',
};

function reducer(state: CounterState = initialState, action: PayloadAction<Payload<CounterState>>) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_FIELD':
      const nState = { ...state };
      const { fieldName, value } = action.payload;
      nState[fieldName] = value;  // TSC throws error
      return nState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

The `T0` type is correct:

```
type T0 = {
    fieldName: "id";
    value: string;
} | {
    fieldName: "status";
    value: "idle" | "loading" | "failed";
} | {
    fieldName: "email";
    value: string;
} | {
    fieldName: "password";
    value: string;
}
```

When I assign the value to state from `action.payload` use `nState[fieldName] = value;`, got error:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"idle" | "loading" | "failed"'.(2322)
```

TSC does not infer correct `value` type for `fieldName` value. Why? How can I solve this? Actually, the `value` type inferred is always `string`. I expect that when the `fieldName` is `status`, the `value` type should be inferred to `'idle' | 'loading' | 'failed'`.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghiANgezgEwIIGNgEtkB2APDFALxQBuyuaANFACpQQAewEBaAzlN8ACdcBAObk+g4SIYBZcQQiUIAhgFF5i5QD5xAbwBQUI1DAIU6AFywA3IeOhIVxrYC+UAGRQAFAG0ZAXRZ2Th4oHwUlAUCAfihdNysDYygAWwhgOCsZVwBKD28fVUC2Di5ecM0oqFj4qES7I2UBZAErVVz9fTYwFuAoYQ4BADM4LGgAYWQAVwJBgGUMjji7Wit+IVFbI344YCnuKwByWkQIQ6gAHyhD8zQpc6vDkdxTtEOtlhS4F7XJTbtTNxuAB3FpoX4bESuToOaDwJCoNBERg6ChJMIAaX6BCgAGsICBkEMmP56skhrgIIg0AA5OBpKwYj5GShwRBTCBOHwY-wfFyuHz4wnExi8-SwpgABnE8NuREmM3miwgWls+iwhH42NweDZC12nKgCtmyn1SzRK3B10OdDsEC+P2ttqMgJBYKONrsOz2B2uJzOtv5nSGMxw+BxAggaCmYwEXm9huNSoN4mEOtweuVDFGeEIVlliOwueIBfQ8umJoEZpVWjy6JBOqwAAtvDnwwA6WF1hpQLBwbjQQ4AVRgABEMIxVAB9ABiAElVAAZUeHCw9owaghagjVvRQdsHhNQIPJDeavq6KAUqm0+kQBis9nQNwUNuEdumBHoZnGHfKnzXtSdJpIEFCPhyP5GJGewCDif4Gj+aAQCMUyIMAa6nlA0FTLBEgIXYLj6C4QA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error because `fieldName` might be a `status` which is allowed to be only `'idle' | 'loading' | 'failed'` whereas you are trying to assign much wider type - `string`. Try to comment `status` in each object and type and error will disappear.

Your type of payload itself is correct:

```js
type T0 = Payload<CounterState>;
```

but try to get a type of `value` from this union:`Payload<CounterState>['value']`, you will get a string. This is exactly what you are getting here: `const { fieldName, value } = action.payload;`.

TypeScript is able to infer it with `condition statement`:

```js
function reducer(state: CounterState = initialState, action: PayloadAction<Payload<CounterState>>) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_FIELD':
      const nState = { ...state };
      const { fieldName, value } = action.payload;
      if (fieldName === 'status') {
        nState[fieldName] = value;
      } else {
        nState[fieldName] = value;
      }
      return nState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
```

but is looks a bit crazy, is not it ?:D

In this case we need to trick typescript:

```js
type PayloadAction<P = void, T extends string = string, M = never, E = never> = {
  payload: P;
  type: T;
} & ([M] extends [never] ? {} : {
  meta: M;
}) & ([E] extends [never] ? {} : {
  error: E;
})

export interface CounterState {
  id: string;
  status: 'idle' | 'loading' | 'failed';
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

type Payload<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    fieldName: K;
    value: T[K];
  };
}[keyof T];
type T0 = Payload<CounterState>;

const initialState: CounterState = {
  id: '',
  email: '',
  password: '',
  status: 'idle',
};

const setProperty = <
  S extends CounterState,
  Prop extends keyof S,
  Value extends S[Prop]
>(state: S, prop: Prop, value: Value) => ({
  ...state,
  [prop]: value
})

function reducer(state: CounterState = initialState, action: PayloadAction<Payload<CounterState>>) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_FIELD':
      const { fieldName, value } = action.payload;
      return setProperty(state, fieldName, value)

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NrGDzm)

---

**UPDATE**

> But don't know why we should use this trick

Consider this example:

```js
type Foo = {
  a: 'a'
}

type Bar = {
  a: 'b'
}


type Result = Foo | Bar

type Test = Result['a'] // "a" | "b"
```

`Test` is a union of `a` and `b` it is expected and nothing new here.

However, if you add another one type to a union with `a: string` it will change `Test`.

```js
type Foo = {
  a: 'a'
}

type Bar = {
  a: 'b'
}

type Baz = {
  a: string
}
type Result = Foo | Bar | Baz

type Test = Result['a'] // string
```

Or in other words: `"a" | string` evaluates to `string` since `string` is much wider type.

TypeScript returns the most common type. See docs [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#unions-with-common-fields) and [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#working-with-union-types)

In above case `string` is a super type and `a` is a subtype. When we have a union of subtype and supertype it is always safer to use only properties from supertype.
Consider another one example:

```js
type A = {
  a: 'a'
}

type B = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b'
}

type Result = A | B

type Test = Result['a'] // ok
type Test2 = Result['b'] // error
```

`A` is a supertype and `B` is a subtype of `A`.
You are only allowed to use props from supertype because thay are always safe to obtain.

This is why in your case `value` is evaluated as a string, because it is always safer to consider it as a `string`. If you add condition, like I did in my first example `if (fieldName === 'status')`  TS will be able to infer type of `value` and `fieldName`, otherwise TS will stick with most safer types.

Comment: It works. But don't know why we should use this trick? I really don't understand how tsc works, looks the same. Besides, why `value` is inferred as a `string` type instead of maybe `'idle' | 'loading' | 'failed' | string`? I test it, it seems TSC can only infer this type to `string`. E.g. `type T1 = 'idle' | 'loading' | 'failed' | string` => `string`.

Comment: From js's point of view, it looks the same. In order to get the TS type knocked down correctly, affecting my JS implementation?

Comment: @slideshowp2 I made an update